# Add custom header to all responses in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Simple question, and I am sure it has a simple answer but I can't find it.

I am using WebAPI and I would like to send back a custom header to all responses (server date/time requested by a dev for syncing purposes).

I am currently struggling to find a clear example of how, in one place (via the global.asax or another central location) I can get a custom header to appear for all responses.

---

Answer accepted, here is my filter (pretty much the same) and the line i added to the Register function of the WebApi config.

**NOTE: The DateTime stuff is NodaTime, no real reason just was interested in looking at it.**

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("ServerTime", Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()).ToString());
    }
```

Config Line:

```
config.Filters.Add(new ServerTimeHeaderFilter());
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

For that you can use a custom ActionFilter (`System.Web.Http.Filters`)

```
public class AddCustomHeaderFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
       actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("customHeader", "custom value date time");
    }
}
```

You can then apply the filter to all your controller's actions by adding this in the configuration in Global.asax for example :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AddCustomHeaderFilter());
```

You can also apply the filter attribute to the action that you want without the global cofiguration line.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct. Sometimes the content of a response could be `null` however. You should do `actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add` instead.

Comment: Action filters could work but be careful that message handlers could prevent you even getting that far. Thus you could land up with some responses missing the header.

Comment: Also, bare in mind that Authorization filters run before Action filters and if your authorization filter would deny access, the custom action filter would never get to fire at all.

Comment: The problem with these answers is that they only apply a header to the html page, not the CSS pages, images, javascript, etc. Is this really a problem? If you run a penetration test with ZAP, it complains about the missing headers. How do you add a header to all files in an MVC app?

Comment: OnActionExecuted only fires if the action was executed.  So if another filter prevented it from executing, then your filter won't run.  This is common if you have an Authorization Filter in place and the context is not authenticated and you rely on your action filter to run on UnAuthenticated requests.

To get around this, you should implement OnActionExecuting, and implement both the async and sync versions of it.

Comment: So this was working for me and now it's not.  HttpActionExecutedContext.Response is null now for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

Previous answers to this question don't address what to do if your controller action throws an exception.  There are two basic ways to get that to work:

**Add an exception filter**:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class HeaderAdderExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Response == null)
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, context.Exception);

        context.Response.Content.Headers.Add("header", "value");
    }
}
```

and in your WebApi setup:

```
configuration.Filters.Add(new HeaderAdderExceptionFilter());
```

This approach works because WebApi's default exception handler will send the HttpResponseMessage created in a filter instead of building its own.

**Replace the default exception handler:**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;
using System.Web.Http.Results;

public class HeaderAdderExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, context.Exception);
        response.Headers.Add("header", "value");

        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);
    }
}
```

and in your WebApi setup:

```
configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new HeaderAdderExceptionHandler());
```

You can't use both of these together.  Okay, well, you can, but the handler will never do anything because the filter already converted the exception into a response.

Super important to note that *as written, this code will send all the exception details to the client*.  You probably don't want to do this in production, so check out all the available overloads on CreateErrorResponse() and pick which one suits your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of the above two solutions worked for me. They wouldn't even compile. Here's what I did. Added:

```
filters.Add(new AddCustomHeaderFilter());
```

to `RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)` method in FiltersConfig.cs and then added

```
public class AddCustomHeaderFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   {
       actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("ServerTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: i think this was WebAPI 1, not sure if 2 (if that's what you are using) has slightly different bindings

Comment: Yes most likely that is the explanation. I am using WebAPI 2.0. But I think my version will be useful for people now looking how to add a custom header.

Comment: I don't think this works when an exception is thrown.  How do you add headers to ALL responses?

Answer (score 6):

Julian's answer led me to have to create the filter but only using the the System.Web (v4) and System.Web.Http (v5) namespace (MVC packages were not part of this particular project this was used on.)

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
...
public class AddCustomHeaderActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Response.Headers.Add("name", "value");
    }
}
```

And add it to the global.asax to have it used on every controller/action

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AddCustomHeaderActionFilterAttribute());
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by the messagehandler easily, it will handle both ok response and exception case.

```
 public class CustomHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       // add header to request if you want
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        response.Headers.Add("cutomKey", "cutomValue");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Add it in the config

```
 config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomHeaderHandler());
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my requirement, below single line of code serves the purpose.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Key", "Value")
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<string> vals;`
`response.Headers.TryGetValues("Key", out vals);`
`string value = vals?.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

I combined the normal and exception path in one class:

```
public class CustomHeaderAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IExceptionFilter
{
    private static string HEADER_KEY   { get { return "X-CustomHeader"; } }
    private static string HEADER_VALUE { get { return "Custom header value"; } }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        return (new CustomHeaderAction() as IActionFilter).ExecuteActionFilterAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken, continuation);
    }

    public Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return (new CustomHeaderException() as IExceptionFilter).ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);
    }

    private class CustomHeaderAction: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            { 
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add(HEADER_KEY, HEADER_VALUE);
            }
        }
    }

    private class CustomHeaderException : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Response == null)
            {
                context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, context.Exception);
            }

            context.Response.Content.Headers.Add(HEADER_KEY, HEADER_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy but at least it gives me one place to control my additional headers. For now it's just static content but you could always hook it up to some sort of dictionary generator/factory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to add a new header to the whole controller, just add "services.AddHttpContextAccessor();" to startup.cs then create your controller

```html
public class EnController : Controller{

        public EnController(IHttpContextAccessor myHttpAccessor)
        {

            myHttpAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Language", "en-US");

        }

       ... more methods here... 

}
```