# Manually adding attribute to request body after authentication

Tags: asp.net, http, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API 2 application. When an HTTP request is going to come in which contains user authentication credentials, before it reaches the defined route(for which I am using Attribute routing), I want to somehow add a filter so that it can authenticate the user, and upon successful authentication, I want to fetch an ID from the repository and add it to the request body.

Is it possible to add a filter before the request reaches the controller's action? And more importantly, is it possible to add some value to the request body after the authentication by the filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As i cant comment i'm adding it here.

This article gives several options on how to handle authentication in Asp.net Web Api:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

But if you insist on going the custom filter way another option could be something like this:

[Add custom header to all responses in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349447/add-custom-header-to-all-responses-in-web-api)

Here he adds a custom header to the response by using System.Web.Http.Filters.

```
public class AddCustomHeaderFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
       actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("customHeader", "custom value goes here");
    }
}
```

and of cause adds in to the filters:

```
config.Filters.Add(new AddCustomHeaderFilter());
```

Comment: This helps. Thanks. But I am more interested in knowing that whether something can be added in the 'Request' after filtering before we pass it to the controller.

Comment: Would this not be the case as long as you put it last? Like [Authorize] [MyCustomFilter]. The custom filter would run after all other filters.

Comment: I dont know if this is any help, but here is something about the order they are executed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterscope(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is never a good idea to modify what client has sent in the Request body and headers. I believe you can use `Proeperties` property on `Request` object. The whole pipeline will have access to it.

```
Request.Properties.Add("UserId", "2");
```