# ASP.Net MVC customize Attribute to replace the same code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In about half of my Action methods in ASP.Net MVC, I need to repeat some code like "try/catch the whole Action" or "change the HTTP response header". I don't want to copy and paste the same code. How can I write a custom attribute to help me add this code?

Comment: Can you add some snippet of your code?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For global error handling on all your MVC methods, and also unhandled errors have a look there: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/handling-errors-effectively-in-asp.net-mvc/

To add a reponse header to all reponses, have a look here:
[Add custom header to all responses in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349447/add-custom-header-to-all-responses-in-web-api)

Comment: no I do not only want to add some custom header. for example, I want all request with Model state invalid response "invalid". How can I create such a attribute? (English is not my native lang hope you won't mind that)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/clean-up-your-web-api-controllers-with-model-validation-and-null-check-filters/), this does what you want for the Model validation part